# deploying Rails 3.1 namespaced assets to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, sass

I have a Rails 3.1 application running on Heroku Cedar and it has a custom built Admin panel.
Admin is just a namespaced controller/view combination which live in controllers/admin and in views/admin.
I also 'namespaced' the assets: called them assets/javascripts/admin.js.coffe and assets/stylesheets/admin.css.scss and include both from layouts/admin/application.html.haml

<strike>Heroku perfectly compiles application.(css.scss|js.coffee) to a javascript/stylesheet files. When I visit frontend application it just works.</strike>

But when I visit '/admin' I get the following error:

When I visit website in production I get the following error:

```
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.5/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:46:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.5/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.2.5/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2011-09-19T15:47:18+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-19T15:47:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

According to [Heroku's documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting) I don't need to add gems like `therubyracer-heroku` to my gemfile. My admin asset files are manifest files and are similar to application asset manifests:

```
# application.js.coffee
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs

# admin.js.coffee
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
```

Any thoughts?

**Update 19 sept:** As it turns out, admin assets are never compiled into `public/assets` and neither are present in `public/assets/manifest.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your application's PATH, as also mentioned in the Heroku documentation you linked?

I had this same problem, adding 'bin' to the PATH solved it.

Comment: Yeah, did that too. Didn't help.